# Discussion of Type Interpretation using Predicate Functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAggcgZQJIOAJwJYDsDmAeAFSggA9gIsATAZymvWxygB8osBXAWwCMI0Wo3DDmzAB3APYSANhACGWKAF46DXAD5lUAAYAdEgEZuAbQAkAbwIBfTtoCwAKFF8AZnIDG0eMijnHASEJiMgoaVUxcAQ4ePnUACgA3OWl2CAAuKAIASgzvFDV8AnUAtHlKCSxpEChS6ghgXMR8iPwABnUAGhKyiqqaiBxSDIAlAYBREjBHK0d3aTlqWgAFNAlgCTzg8ipaADF2LHdgDArfbrqxFQAifSNjVs4rqAWodwr6bsGSLTiAelvuLpjHE4gB%20NK6SgAagA3FkAFSgyFQrKcX44LKOAJvLD0NDsI4SNBxLJnBz%20fzUdiQYlXJIpCBXDpQK6lYDsNCKPSGEwWempGzaK6Y8kzBxinH0WBNLRYCAAdygKzWGyaJOetAOAGssBJ5YoXnksQ5QJAoFqICBaCo8YwolxePxWNQQDwZFBfr86AALInAb0KShQSgQOZyNByY6nFxEpWrGmgADSluNpugAAkZCG0NQ8EgtAoQJoVDA0BGQHnNKwALJyMB4C1W5lIYoOVPgaAANV2eBgxYCrBgxgAuiOB1Ba-XG9RmUPh63-DW6w3LTPYOox%20Sl1PV8zJyum%20vW2moMNu73%201vYCPN4vfFBjImMtPh7kR1AxXfzA%20n%20bV6-YA-W9WG-R9n3-DJQIAGXAq0AJgD8P0cE8CDkbhZAAYQgaRpC0YwMIqbYGnCRhmyoIY2AdPhh2NWZ5kWTI0NkPAAhgLpyV2IlOC2UJaHPPstH41tND8ckwEwJJyFeQi5GwPgMk4tBOACcSMEk6B1jAAARNSMGzLQriUK4VIkyNoGoPSIB0hJLP4a4WFYYyxNMqTOD06zbIMgQnP8VT1KgWQXGAAAhIl9OuRyTLUszpOkDzs2tNgFSgBB6jwaJHXiEVfJc6BVnlGBcQwWVkv3DK%20GZcqnRIjQSSi-yQzcdhpGAYY9UKiyDIAZgATh8vyYreaQOuKlQ5UVMqqLQSqpoEW1auygapMauRmuAAjhqKgyABY%20vqwbsM2iyAHkEj4TAQxKibl20CwqqsDo7qmqxtFnJpUBaLLjX8SV0AJdZiUoSM5AUrioAAMigITSVEikY34OJZDEOQoAkFxg2BgA6fkIGoElsrh2NEfqQRUfRuRseSVI8ayAmKQwdG4ncb1Qy1RSCAkD7GDibgNSVcM5E4eo%20FzNM0deFn3DZokOa5jRaYCCkKX9fKksVMYyyJOIrjGWQhawMRylxtg1igAMzueKADgwABHVI%20kauSg3WOWmCF-0JEoYVFf9DBqExnFgFkuU7IxoOAjFAJfnheFT3qDlcUtqqoH9SMoGwSgMHcMzaHlAMxADMBIDlSg0gCKBY-L2PY%200VptAyHGoHlF5dTEC5njEMAJAsqMsCriudAMeuoEb5vaHbtOu57k4%20-JAea4AJmHqeMF7puXmpIHyGdiQR6piAq9%20AILjifLYLXIbz%20ZHHchhn20GqWGKSRq2wC36AVAMZl8omP3gGoDIkgZDyFnkrBmUA4h%200nHEX2-tA7Bz4LTMkSt-A-xIH-RKsCA4yTkmgTGAY8b5RFIremjNfTSBoNArB8DcFIO-J6Ccy5JwLhQeAuIABCNBGDSTUJwSHTGJ98qVVKsuacs4sp0wpAwgAeuA1WRtqBYAAORiFIH-ZkchKBBlXnzFG40oCcDrCQik2E6jp0Zrwg2CC8GDGAKfPUWR2H4IWEzGQCtyQoP8JvGKKgF4ei9OA4wQihrDmCBg5k7c2QJz3gyFOu9vHb2%20igyxQdcGY1sfY%20UjiBH1FcdIa%20%209JFWGINIMx9CvT7lLOWVsxj-BsM4XqX%209BqA8O9H7bBVi0mCL1LOMscgQAwLaf7aIG0WmSP8KY6AbChrp0UCk6x6TclEPYeMrxb8fFQAXrUhhAABf%20ABaYQupSi1MmU3NpsgIHsLybMlOQyOmpP4Rk5ZSD5lpOeQ4pxYB2DUG9HEDgOFiEeKVm8p5SzPnGHSlNdQIStA42MZ%20CkxSzmiWMVw5pWhVbYDue0mhIckmkIgeQyhdZBm4r4YgmG-jYB9IrMw2p9T0X-1WXnDAlyOGZNuaCyltTlb3LxXwTG3zfn-JEWAfGpzSlTIsfyilaBIVVXUPlYczi8ZDXcZ4tZ78tBbOBXy8lnSQ4KuhcqnJdihoFIZEUkpZTqVVP6b2WlLCwGMwafKJpzLeWsvZdcrFczZWGp5XqkFAbHmCuFX8%201AysEjJkGMyVZjpnumxdy%20VUKYhoCVXqYcqyEkf02dsr0ezqCHJwMcg%20wazneugBymZKbQ3WONRmrN8oc2tINWGtNirTURv%20c1aQ4zU1Nsysq4dsRYUqHhXqxF-gZ1RM5K-d%20itinZ2AMzCBEA77AslMAzG50tabpIfOxQrRl0R2%20tHWOABxeotBAz9HZJyO9ihV4QG4mnFGK815BJ6bFUJsYDiOxLuYk2xADYPzCRi%20ER9yQfPlFfWK58ciAVYIBiALgnbILqYzKBpLU10JIWw4l1AqENtoZI49OK4FysWXYohoJaN5LppR1NjH6OY0jHEdNmV1Vno8URrMJG8NkZDhqikLGROCs49x2I7GMm8Y8RJjtCzpPdocQx1T0KFOzu%20rYhelAYDuE8IsIkNMMjGDEX%20K0I5RyhKfmw3D4r8NbpdUSwTpHlPkbRfHBdWD8pQTQqYzGhjxXfCUJoYwJBmS8OkAF3gpSc3UtTenWg%205LNpd3EeI9Pn-XtP84F0pwXSVhYi1Fh8mMKtRrJcMrgoysgqpCyCAA%20syDApJwvp3q6SBhyW-aMJ3IeOcLDEUCYoUJpzkm0BidQTlqjDyFmNbiC1zrygIsYGi7K2LBXqCJZ65NlL-WDxrj7LeGbj7cvUcDXgxby22urYfOt8rlXaXVcxrG0p9WiviqW8yAAVu1zQ-3dtel67QOct5I6wfqKhdCEAqtUqU-7PTBmjO42oKZkkX2QQ-vlMyHEiWOs4ixzMjrWC4N47cQxl2BR1SglBCyYUpJIeUnqAgSy8U%20BxEzgkDI80MRYawRZEMHPQ7c8Voj89bZyQXGrO5XS2YudqV5wUFz-gsFuUoCLrQYvFOzdgZL4%200OJDaXl5z7nyuWiq6wZpLXKgdfib10Mg35JL2ZCGYIMKfAm5stwrwAxGBNalCDKcf0eVhDejbpZCuMGWfACguhkKnviSSDQNmC3jArf3MCon1PXuVAp%20zOLx3ftnf%20E0Zr03aAYBBT4BtLguI4gVcxhnUguMMhVRHKr%20GECX7FXFi3kguN23UbipX-25fIEEwl6KKOMcoBICwN8tuvpmpBj9wAP3X9yO42hN-aFgbvrfthN9QDAOGMQ4tQ-PC2m8S60HDetXakVAiIY8ZN4oAwNvD4%20fMibx34ctmXeRML8xgCQv%20FWWA-66MH%20mAQ%20JC3exMYgWoZMbAkifmT%20FkZqcQWo18U%20xe1Aku-gruC%20S%20PoEgq%20gg0Ae%20AIxgh%20%20%20QydBx%206%20p%205%20KBV%20CgnUt%200A9%200u9QG0I0L%20uMjeFWMBGAX%20xgP%20UAf%20U0NmneWGCBIBYBUhEBUBYGn%20LS8BwBJMyB4sWAaBm2I0WBOBI8eB52VGpeFwWEOEI0p050lkb%20Ih4GYhACD4eQrs4BmMt05g90j03hz02gshiWT8ChJMoBHhkBKBohcBwKIRSBKBehxi1Ch0NhZ0ZYlkRhuBReZh%20uM%20UuOU0UUkngOEikhiwA5AxIRR0grs6euAFO0gAA6npP6O3lNAjrNl4ZUa7FYBYE8FcJjKUJAJxkNI0ZQP6FkC9AItIFnBAHEK0HUSMWMUhHkUtNAENPXgAFISC4JMyHQuEw6YSHQjjfx6gL4hhhZQCtCq6UaVH%20xB4EgzFxB4jMjGCVEECkDADMjc62SnGkAE4iQkK-TSScBgBsr5quIGwf41E4CfGV5QkGTCirbGJeFk71AjQwB0YnHkRlZfHZg-EkDjEWCBwf7dHmB5D9G4z1Akk4l8AvQEpsLUloB4lQB4BzbvYtL3gMLgKVEHatx3LQD0RiBrGcAvoGg1B6gErYYQIxYi7%20wEKK42S4lYlIKcnoywKxT15kEUF%204xg4R6gQBr7VAoxCA4CDD8AMm1KUZ4hQBQhAkgmyA7E4RvFkAbbtJC5WSV7dZejXESA8CYa1BrTe7%20iCDCCmnBiV4SmWnoDWm2mgkOnSBOkfFzYa4i6ekPrRJvC%20nAb%20ktSBneiqCBjhhBjmnArM4O5mFWk2kZl2kzGvHvGpnemZn6n9BUgtTLrMhXDey5EBC2JokYnwaUQZp1EtEZqq5sJJHWFFS2FpEhiqpxBeH5QPSEkyAvRIKI4BzJGTmpEXQQCMbzl6iLnmBDQrmKyAn5SCFaB5Cvb5SGFwakh05zYrRrRtQFRFQEyAlDTnklhqgxY3m5LqpQD3lYKPktT8GvlZHRJnmezQCVkyCCGl62IDnPk0z3iUaOavYCpTYAVzYYUCIYAABe0AGQrGsguAQZzOCFbJ6o9mZC7mwmnmomzG%20B2CW28W-sJFOA-o4FC6tY-oRWJAwhmMxgTerGOMNMDWxW92JAmM7FYx2U5FJM%20WrFVFis9SaFzmaZC6p2lGQlFWrG04JINEXZUOgpMgcWpiyl-GrqxGHml2naq5s274Kp6pwpd6pQJsyMBidY38s2b6YAoAzwtKJ57wbcJMY0yUqUwAR2WU1K5Q7lqgRIeUEAgx-8isCBgJKMl%20k2lMDINMqZ3e8g66jc9aqxcqJCOlHGmM%20ln28MYwHgfyJWdA9QHGWicQ%20JqZ0i0i5exAdVKBq8tA04cSfJjVwAXFigUamMLgqwnAjx9Q9Zju5kJMLwCgAV5Y8FJM9ARIcggwBAHYVFGlXIFgalk2d5LIk4TwGQVwUaVwVgeAFg1ldFtl1iJ1VwZ1UAF1V1Vg6g2gSx3ZClcg8oWkwMe1a5GFP1xlKcTE8gsOgNQcJIIwQkWGDm426FcqBGwKo2JKE29FlKWG%20qj1uC3mZhx03Av2oYwAE1U1YwThQhtS5V0czJGWh4jNx26grN0eqa4l32FmlozIIWfxD4jY7EmqxNpNRwFNPpVN6hcQ5VfNXWxidMM6qa2WRNJNZN4tnAktsBeMdNsceAzNs4I4bN0GHNBMI2NFY2Nl82XmwKINNGjWDVItatk1Et1N2tTeJAbao12FpVRl%20R-kCFmAOAEeoUuexIbR2RWeCeId2YAiYAUxdiHZWQ5JqRdQmOv2WxWA2sCJkOx8Qcxw7gp%20akawUaeAwU8Q4YaAGQwUN4QRQVuIYg0QSFBYZY0lFAHF3oddUobJzd8qrQKqMlHdeRRBXoGEpQMUeiyUFd-SuZQ16AHBU8TZmc%20sFk7wndYg2ZxE1dtmF5tK6tcQ34A9w5oyH4zI6o4WJC41zt01B9bdzRiFeotAVgBMQKUiXouwPuQ1%20iU91Q8oq8eZV%20c9uIC9QYolqVWh69eoWgrQMIYpioLJjdD9MD%20UUIKIuNsRsUUDMDMy8DtWcaWDMgKDquDuLZwALxMgo4yqPdOOo4ISJCiKpZlGG9FhedWcUAV9%20mjtRwQQ7xvEVma4AAqjxDsHw%20InEBICTZBD%20LcgQABNBLcvw-BIhE-VhoCZpJrc4VdIdpZnI9igo7kB%20PEJw%20TVEXjOI-9m%20cFbMiHOo8bGFddOKuVWo67ZzdjmVhIPzZFsIvY3EEY3uq7WI6SC8NzYNoAZ7brmYfovsTMdgNY67XJRel6BzOUBkL-ThK8GPVJCjDgBdGwZDQQdLiwwXVSNwNk3pHECzOHsRFVMyL-aMd6MOY6B4UHLDnsZDXgIWBuLXVLqlQcEcDPFALYrWCQFEwsX8lSp%20MztTi0BZRSICd%20IpaYnUWZaUohCoDkbM5Y-lNQOmHIGdMs4lAs4VgPVAOwioKeh4u%20XGjs3s9tloENPs63aRXmacxcUkoCVvHIFE1oCicAFE-DmvYXQkMXWWFoFE0KkXcAFVh81ExY-Xc5VgKM4lCCUC5Cy3Y1iQnknUXiXUVGgDsYhwkNNs7sxAPs1hTMuZk3harFPs2Q9IHiSqlM9zF1uSZQPcXELUnEIYmVjfU8yfbA3i8Gv4Jy3IN8Cycc%20DJDENFGrS0yTaQYMOAxtQyc9cODAifTscxkFy0LSgpcYrC-Wrh2P0Ky30xUAQNSJcioMYFE1YdIEcTVNCQOY6IZRs3CxhlgMkFGtrsDGC4tmVoyUqfdk-D9JYzcXhO7e2VcCqncZ4Njh4O4FwM1JGESMyAKREmfpAXjhyKUAbK1hoshtG73Ga3HR-P8UPYSnEBTMc0oCoMVHKw5K8Fmx-sqyyKq1urUpcw0U0d6HibY09pjFVtQOm9GQYJ9jdn9gDunFAPslAL9lO1ACO%202yGzIIi3c8u12z2-7PbfdkKQi129QJFjmou3C5UaM1oKNGc1ha0G9bFIiyy2yzAmsJm5haTqbJWRyOMoCfDKUdvN8-yodCUZGOUYjAsImSe129GYO8tbHOrnLgqYKgPfq65nEF%204B02S84nc8EZgm-MADEKj8n8sYCh2Ufqa1oe8GtpXG9h0m9NA22WB-syH3QihGQ5ZR5wImwDCmyB2m8tXK4ZXQ88Xax2Qx6Ei8AWzPEW7IFkPcHxzbbNpkkSzc6xVhR2de1gtntHYgtGTFhsRnZzjcd-LK-O6SDaX5pUxp2gMuvqy-Ic6e2c8cfKMs6lGfhGADPCSpYzFs9cyS9tkQ4CXzqSyoIc5uxJR1q7K1dNjZ%20BzaAUA89Gw8Vq-eMc8ox1sc5oFy1hRq55WVrqzbXqI50lQLK52s-cm6SLpoQjL3rckF0Q8G661xKh5QDa7%207iv%20-V8R8SP59tsYBgMOPZ8s6M5Iulc-lBc10jqiUVOiXEHAFNJPsOwx4N5Yy4P2k1yoMiZHUFOZySRwRgIISSUR9vDaySWSbUJSRYILuzpXrSXqm6x67St16EioEtzhE1zaTd8NHdz13Q3xu5xAoS15-s754t219vAF9S9tljq1a1hO%20OdIAB%2013EGF-iXUfXoi-d9NjIrWBaOPByNAAVXma%20txH1lftQILNALU0GS8Hj71f-NJHR4OxUJnJEDu-k0rICSzJorXrsVoPt-qQ8761D-dp45O7x3zNa4dHTDIqPfIOQLQGL2kwT7QPlT1ez4XtupY%20nU7KD9p8KZsdsSr5zzhBoWW6o8bvHkFARJyHnic26v1%20B6CIkfcjbpXuSclZkrb3U8Z3NqV5Xm9cYh2QCZY%20JBAOmGUHwPw%20RGgFMXKKN8xTp9scYvr2gDa8F1zTy%203Xyz1xO8YNbsbiLi79L8TE81kKR6L5DTa9Nqo5DSHxz2gOH9mFH-mmp1HUnlp6bwnhbyHNGUH9X9mHX3wA31p-coHcHUngSm9%20NQcL8gzHYk3xty31CH7-sn0QMQX5Fx79GYc054V7GDaRryXKSwv3qqZ0HTntmNq8rFX6H7XxHw3xLyDpfzX335H3JN9x4uP4FUPZRu-%20WJjHv9rDQQ8F0BYAESNpG4DyHuCPBncOdBwEt0OBrxHMF4JmBkEzAUIRYeAFAQlAvDqBkMBdPrPrSgAYC0BfYUtsPTYa9N4B42RAe4GQFZg0BhAnMFgJwEHZ8BJdYgQIHwEsDWa9NFgbSgvDsDREmWNgdBmQTXFZk9ABQJ4HFiThpgxoWASa0UD3V6wfYJAQQNoEMD6BuYYgUwL6waC9aAgwbGzVhgMI5Ba8RQVQJoGoD1BagzQazW0GpZ9Ba4TgVWBpTlg9BA2FmiQO0qUtsq1MAytJzEFBxDgEAKQUYnFCyDyB-TZmKzHZicwCg3DEIMIyMbxAzGGQbICINmy%20NxIKoNMJjEZaRBq2UAXxrYmVDrA0wx0FwGIxJpJ08hOAaYEAA)

## Preface

I'm not asking for a solution, per-se. I want to have a discussion of typescript's behavior so I can better understand it better going forward. I'm still open to suggestions of how I could improve my code.

## Post

I'm using TypeScript V4.9.4.

I'm using VSCode with the following configurations:

```
Version: 1.76.2 (user setup)
Commit: ee2b180d582a7f601fa6ecfdad8d9fd269ab1884
Date: 2023-03-14T17:55:54.936Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
Sandboxed: No
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "lib": [
            "ESNext",
            "DOM"
        ],
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [ "**/*.ts" ]
}
```

I've been writing a class to represent, format and print data organized in a table structure. The constructor supports any combination of 2D-nested maps/arrays (Shown in type `VF<A>` below)

I've defined the following types as a part of the class.

###### Type Definitions

```
type keys = string | number | symbol // shorthand declaration for PropertyKey
type Holders<I = any> = Array<I> | Map<keys, I>
type VF<A> = // Valid Formats
    | A[][]
    | Map<keys, A[]>
    | Map<keys, A>[]
    | Map<keys, Map<keys, A>> // this union is the expanded format of Holders<Holders<A>>
type RVF<A> = // Raw (Basic Object) Valid Formats
    | A[][]
    | { [K: keys]: A[] }
    | { [K: keys]: A }[]
    | { [K: keys]: { [L: keys]: A } }
```

The types are implemented in the following class definition.

###### Class Implementation

```
class Table<
    A,
    Form extends VF<A> = VF<A>>
> {
    private container: Form
    // ... other unimportant instance variable declarations

    constructor(data: Form & VF<A>) {
        // ... checking that each element meets a condition
        this.container = data
    }

    // ... The rest of the class implementation
}
```

The following outputs are achieved with sample inputs:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `Map<keys, Map<keys, string>>` | `Table<string, Map<keys, Map<keys, string>>` |
| `Map<keys, number[]>` | `Table<number, Map<keys, number[]>>` |
| `Map<keys, boolean>[]` | `Table<boolean, Map<keys, boolean>[]>` |
| `(string | number)[][]` | `Table<string | number, (string | number)[][]>` |

I've defined the following functions for narrowing the type of `this.container` within class methods.

###### Type Predicate Functions

```
// equivalent to c is Map<keys, Array<A> | Map<keys, A>>
function isMap<A>(c: Holders<Holders<A>>): c is Map<keys, Holders<A>> {
    return c instanceof Map
}

// equivalent to c is Map<keys, Map<keys, A>> | Array<Map<keys, A>>
function holdsMap<A>(c: Holders<Holders<A>>): c is Holders<Map<keys, A>> {
    return [...c.values()][0] instanceof Map
}
```

I've implemented them in the following layout in multiple places, which usually narrows `this.container` to the correct type (shown by the comments).

###### Standard Implementation of Predicate functions

```
if (isMap(this.container)) {
    if (holdsMap(this.container)) {
        this.container // type: Map<keys, Map<keys, A>>
        return 
    }
    this.container // type: Map<keys, A[]>
    return
}
if (holdsMap(this.container)) {
    this.container // type: Map<keys, A>[]
    return
}
this.container // type: A[][]
return
```

Again, this layout interprets `this.container` correctly in every instance except for the following one. I solved it by manually casting `this.container`, but I have no clue why it doesn't work in this one instance.

###### Getter where it doesn't work properly

```
// getter defined in Table class
/** Returns the container as an object that can be output by `console.table()` */
get tableableData(): RVF<A> {
    if (isMap(this.container)) {
        if (holdsMap(this.container)) {
            this.container // should be interpreted as Map<keys, Map<keys, A>>
            // is actually interpreted as Form & Map<keys, Holders<A>> & Map<keys, Map<keys, A>>
            return Object.fromEntries(
                [...<Map<keys, Map<keys, A>>>this.container].map(([key, map]) => [key,
                    Object.fromEntries([...map])])
                                        // ^^^ Error thrown here when this.container
                                        // is not cast to Map<keys, Map<keys, A>>
            )
        }
        this.container // should be interpreted as Map<keys, A[]>
        // is actually interpreted as Form & Map<keys, Holders<A>>
        return Object.fromEntries([...<Map<keys, A[]>>this.container])
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     // Error thrown here when this.container is not cast to Map<keys, A[]>
    }
    if (holdsMap(this.container))
        return this.container.map(x => Object.fromEntries([...x]))
                 // ^^^^^^^^^ Here, it is interpreted correctly
    return this.container // Also interpreted correctly here
}
```

For reference, I have the following method where the type of `this.container` is inferred correctly.

###### Method where it works properly

```
// method defined in Table class
/** Gets and returns an item at a position [row, col] or undefined if no entry exists */
get(row: keys, col: keys): A {
    if (isMap(this.container)) {
        if (holdsMap(this.container))
            return this.container.get(row)?.get(col) // container is Map<Map>
        return this.container.get(row)?.at(<number>col) // contianer is Map<Array>
    }
    if (holdsMap(this.container))
        return this.container.at(<number>row)?.get(col) // container is Array<Map>
    return this.container.at(<number>row)?.at(<number>col) // container is Array<Array>
}
```

Does anyone have a clue as to why this would happen? Is this something that can be fixed/accounted for, or is this just an issue with typescript itself?

Comment: Could you please just throw all your code into a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/Q) so we don't have to scrape it off the post? It looks like there's some code missing as well (which would be essential in reproducing the problem).

Comment: @vr. I added a link to the playground at the top of the post

Comment: This is because type predicates produce intersections if the output type isn't seen as a direct subtype of the input type, and that intersections of things with same-named methods are treated as having overloaded methods, which don't compose well.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, please tell me what I'm missing (and maybe [edit] to pare down the example? it's vanishingly rare that hundreds of lines of code are needed to repro an issue suitable for Stack Overflow).